# Easy Count-Down Counters Integer vs Unsigned

Tags: vhdl

Rather than having to build counters as follows -

```
signal my_counter : unsigned(3 downto 0) := to_unsigned(9, 4);
signal reset_value : unsigned(3 downto 0) := to_unsigned(9, 4);
--...
--...
process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        counter <= counter - 1;
        if counter = 0 then
            counter <= reset_value;
            -- raise flag telling other logic to do stuff
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Could you do this with an integer count down with a range? and therefore you wouldn't need to have the reset_value? Could this look something like...

```
signal my_counter_int : integer range 0 to 9 := 9;
--...
--...
process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        counter <= counter - 1;
        if counter = 0 then
            -- raise flag telling other logic to do stuff
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

I'm just seeing whether you can have an implied roll over to 9 with an integer with a set range.

Comment: Unsigned type will roll over when it gets to 0 (back to 2**N-1 where N is the number of bits), integer will give an error when it tries to decrement below it's minimum value in simulation. Real hardware may actually rollover though, giving simulation/hardware missmatch.

Comment: The reason integers don't do modulus arithmetic to powers of two is that they are scalar and don't have bits, they are mathematically defined. Further arithmetic operations aren't defined for modular operation, they follow the ordinary mathematical meaning. The idea of synthesizing integer math by translating to a binary equivalent doesn't extend to non-powers of two modular arithmetic even when using binary number representing types.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own subtype from integer with the proper range (0–9) and define the `counter` variable to be of that type:

```
subtype MY_COUNTER_TYPE is integer range 0 to 9;
signal counter : MY_COUNTER_TYPE := 9;
```

Declare a "rolling decrement" function for your own subtype, which folds the value back to the highest possible value in the range if the decrement would decrease the value under the range:

```
function r_decrement(val : MY_COUNTER_TYPE) return MY_COUNTER_TYPE is
begin
  if val = MY_COUNTER_TYPE'LOW then
    return MY_COUNTER_TYPE'HIGH;
  else
    return val - 1;
  end if;
end function;
```

Now you can use the rolling decrement function of the type without worrying about the resetting the counter manually or checking if the decrement would result in the signal being out of the allowed range:

```
if rising_edge(clk) then

  counter <= r_decrement(counter); -- "rolling" decrement

  if counter = 0;
    -- raise flag telling other logic to do stuff
  end if;

end if;
```

So yes, it is possible. And if you're using a lot of counters like this in your design, you may avoid writing a lot of redundant code when checking the counter limits and resetting the value back to `reset_value` manually.

Comment: There is no useful distinction between declaring a subtype and declaring an object with a subtype indication here as in the original question.  The answer to the yes/no question isn't provided in your answer.

Comment: The only useful distinction is to avoid declaring the highest possible value but use an attribute. Only way that I know to achieve the desired behaviour, is to use a function that decrements and rolls the value.